# scrolling after camera rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I am writing a kind of RTS CameraController in Unity using C#. I already managed to implement the basic functions, but now I am facing a tricky problem. I managed to rotate my camera and afterwards move into the right direction, BUT my scrolling boundaries are not working anymore after rotating (of course because I am just checking for x on the horizontal scrolling, but after rotation I would need to check for y instead). With boundaries I mean the restriction to only scroll until a certain position is reached (x < 0).

I am a bit stuck on how to solve my problem easily. One way would seems to be using conditions and check the rotation before checking for the boundaries, but this doesn't seem like a good aproach for me, just fixing the problem, but not really taking care of the cause. Now my question: Is there an easier or better way to achieve what I am doing? Did I miss something completely?

This is how I want the camera to move in all 4 rotations. The rectangles are my the world, the arrows define my bounds. The camera should always overshoot in backwards direction and stop before the bounds in forward direction.:

[image: intended camera behaviour]

Here is my update method (vertDist and horDist are just defining from when on the mousescroll should start):

```
    void LateUpdate() {
    //LEFT
    if((Input.mousePosition.x < horDist || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
       && transform.position.x > 0)
        transform.Translate(-speed, 0, 0);
    //RIGHT
    if((Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width - horDist || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
       && transform.position.x < world.worldX)
        transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
    //UP
    if((Input.mousePosition.y > Screen.height - vertDist || Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)
       && transform.position.z < world.worldZ - 30) {
        Vector3 temp = transform.eulerAngles;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, speed);
        transform.eulerAngles = temp;
    }
    //DOWN
    if((Input.mousePosition.y < vertDist || Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
       && transform.position.z > -10) {
        Vector3 temp = transform.eulerAngles;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, -speed);
        transform.eulerAngles = temp;
    }

    //ZOOM
    //camera.fieldOfView -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

    //ROTATE
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Rotate")){
        Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position;
        targetPosition += transform.forward * 27;
        //transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Mathf.Sign(Input.GetAxis("Rotate")) * 90, 0), Space.World);
        transform.RotateAround(targetPosition, Vector3.up, Mathf.Sign(Input.GetAxis("Rotate")) * 90);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution! I decided to define a Rect, depending on the current rotation and afterwards check if the camera-position is inside the Rect. Thus I had to mess a bit around with the positions, because I don't know why Rect.Contains() only takes the x- and y- coordinate of a position. My camera just moves along the x- and z-axis, so I did this weird coordinate swapping there:

```
    void LateUpdate() {
    Rect bounds = DefineBounds();
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;

    //LEFT
    if((/*Input.mousePosition.x < horDist ||*/ Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)) {
        pos += transform.TransformDirection(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        //reset pos if out of bounds
        if(!bounds.Contains(new Vector2(pos.x, pos.z)))
            pos -= transform.TransformDirection(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    //RIGHT
    if((/*Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width - horDist ||*/ Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)) {
        pos += transform.TransformDirection(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        //reset pos if out of bounds
        if(!bounds.Contains(new Vector2(pos.x, pos.z)))
            pos -= transform.TransformDirection(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    //UP
    if((/*Input.mousePosition.y > Screen.height - vertDist ||*/ Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)) {
        //Set camera x-angle to 0
        Vector3 temp = transform.eulerAngles;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);

        pos += transform.TransformDirection(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //reset pos if out of bounds
        if(!bounds.Contains(new Vector2(pos.x, pos.z)))
            pos -= transform.TransformDirection(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        //Reset camera x-angle
        transform.eulerAngles = temp;
    }
    //DOWN
    if((/*Input.mousePosition.y < vertDist ||*/ Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)) {
        //Set camera x-angle to 0
        Vector3 temp = transform.eulerAngles;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);

        pos += transform.TransformDirection(0, 0, -speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //reset pos if out of bounds
        if(!bounds.Contains(new Vector2(pos.x, pos.z)))
            pos -= transform.TransformDirection(0, 0, -speed * Time.deltaTime);

        //Reset camera x-angle
        transform.eulerAngles = temp;
    }

    transform.position = pos;

    //ZOOM
    //camera.fieldOfView -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    transform.position = new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel"), pos.z);

    //ROTATE
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Rotate")){
        Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position;
        Vector2 posXZ;

        targetPosition += transform.forward * 27;
        transform.RotateAround(targetPosition, Vector3.up, Mathf.Sign(Input.GetAxis("Rotate")) * 90);
        bounds = DefineBounds();

        pos = transform.position;
        posXZ = new Vector2(pos.x, pos.z);

        while(!bounds.Contains(posXZ)) {
            posXZ = Vector2.MoveTowards(posXZ, bounds.center, 1);

            pos.x = posXZ.x;
            pos.z = posXZ.y;
        }
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
transform.Translate(0, 0, -speed, Space.Self); // For all the Translate, use Space.Self
```

It will only move based on it's local position instead of world position. But you will get what you wanted.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as far as I know Translate() without the last argument is also using Space.Self. Nevertheless this also is not the problem. The scrolling works fine after rotation. I maybe was not clear enough in my description. I have the problem, that my defined condition for boundaries for scrolling are not working after rotation `if((Input.mousePosition.x < horDist || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
     && transform.position.x > 0)`.
When rotated by 90 or 180 degrees this should be `transform.position.y`instead of x.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I got you now. I will look into it when free. But if you found something, just share please.